# How I may use some sort of "OnItemClick" in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What is the proper way to implement some OnItemClick method to the RecyclerView? I'm using HashMap (so there's two different values per one tile in RecyclerView) I'd like to achieve working clicker which will show just exact data as I cliked in RecyclerView.

For example, we have a four tiles with following data:

Lorem1 Ipsum1

Lorem2 Ipsum2

Lorem3 Ipsum4

Lorem4 Ipsum4

I want to have posibility to click just on the left side of RecyclerView (LoremX)

If I tap on the Lorem3, app should display a toast with message Lorem3. What should I do it? I've saw some topics about it, but they are already deprecated.

Comment: I suggest you should maybe use a click listener interface on those different views (if you have 2 different data set in single recyclerview item), then depending on the view clicked, get the value of the text (string).

Answer (score 0):

İnside onBindViewHolder;

```
String text = arrayList.get(position).getTitle(); // LoremX
viewHolder.itemView.tag = text)
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener( object :View.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                listener.onItemClick(item)
            }

        })
```

When creating an adapter, you will call the onclickListener in your view. In that;

```
recyclerview.adapter = Adapter(context!!,items,View.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    val text = v.tag as String?
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, duration)


 }
```